# Sum an array to a matrix diagonal (element wise sum)

Tags: numpy, matrix, diagonal

I need to sum to a matrix diagonal an array (element wise sum):

```
import numpy as np



mx = np.matrix([[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]])
print mx
print '\n'

v = np.array([20,0,10,0.5])
print v
print '\n'
```

This doesn't work:

```
mx = np.diagonal(mx,v)
print mx
```

What can I do? Thank you all

Comment: `mx += np.diag(v)`?

Comment: mx = mx + np.diag(v) works thank you!